# Can I put pegs on any bike?

Tags: bmx

I'm back, again. I'm buying a BMX bike, its a 2021 Kink Gap XL. I wanna put pegs on it, because it doesn't have pegs, and a lot of the tricks I wanna learn require pegs. So, if I buy this bike, will I be able to put pegs on it? Will pegs work on any BMX bike? I don't really care what brand, just as long as something will work. Are there different sizes too?

Answer (score 11):

**To answer your specific BMX Bike**

The King Gap XL 2021 will support pegs. It's safe to say that *any* freestyle BMX bike will support pegs. If you were buying a BMX race bike, there's a chance it doesn't support pegs; BMX race is more focused on being lightweight than freestyle BMX.

**Can I put pegs on any bike**

No, you need to have a certain type of axle to put on pegs. It won't work on a dirt jumper / mountain bike / road bike for example. The axle needs to stick out from the fork / dropouts to have room to house the peg. There's a nut that screws onto the outside of the peg, so if the axle doesn't have the thread, it won't work.

[image: BMX Peg]

[image]

Now compare that to a MTB axle - this is a 15 x 110 boost axle, which is super common on MTB front wheels.

[image]

**Words of advice**

Buy plastic pegs so you don't ruin skatepark ledges

Comment: I'd say that more specifically, the thread needs to extend out beyond the wheel axle nut, as shown in your photo ofc, plenty of axles are just long enough for the nut only. Unless it is default on good bmx bikes, I'm more familiar with kids bikes and other styles of threaded axle..?

Comment: Small note: "Axel" is a figure-skating trick.  "Axle" is the thing on the bike.

Comment: @IronEagle thanks, I updated my answer to correct that.

Comment: Also in BMX bikes both 3/8" and 14mm are common axle sizes, 14mm is usually the rear but can be found on the front as well. Some pegs work for both sizes through the use of an adapter, and some only fit one or the other. Just something to consider. My preference would be pegs with a chromoly core and nylon/plastic outer replaceable sheath.

Comment: Thanks so much for this!